# How to implement 'Remember me' feature in NestJS framework with JWT strategy

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-passport, nestjs-jwt

I'm trying to implement the remember me feature using NestJS framework, I already have the Jwt and local strategy implemented and working like this:

```
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: configService.get('JWT_SECRET'),
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.sub, username: payload.email };
  }
}
```

Local strategy:

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super({ usernameField: 'email' });
  }

  async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

I thought of a way to solve it via the ignoreExpiration flag, do you guys know a way to implement this with the NestJS framework? Tried searching on the docs, but it appears that they don't have that there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future references, I found a solution.

In the jwtService I'm generating a token using the `this.jwtService.sign(payload)` method, on this method I have access to a flag called `expiresIn` (safer than ignoreExpiration flag) so i'm passing a boolean variable to the api to check wheter it has the remember checked or not and setting this flag accordingly. It looks like this

```
remember
  ? (token = this.jwtService.sign(payload, { expiresIn: '60d' }))
  : (token = this.jwtService.sign(payload, { expiresIn: '1d' }));
```